# Handling multiple validation errors returned from a web service

Tags: .net, json, web-services

I have a repository that saves an object through a web service. The repository uses a client to send the object as a JSON package to the web service. The web service will send JSON back with a list of validation errors if validation fails. I'm trying to come up with the best way to get these errors back to the original caller where the errors will be handled in some way. I was planning on simply throwing an exception that would force the caller to deal with the errors but I don't know of a way to attach a list of errors to an exception. I could create a custom exception but this seems kind of hacky. My alternative would be to simply return a list of errors but this doesn't seem ideal either.

The callers to this repository will be batch processes so there won't be any sort of live user to correct any errors.

Comment: So, you need the repository to return the list of errors which comes back from the web service?

Comment: Yes, and I wanted to do this with an exception rather than just returning a list of errors that could be ignored. Or does simply returning a list of errors seem like the best option?

Comment: The exception could be ignored, too. And what do you want the client to do with the error messages? In fact, what do you _expect_ the client to do _about_ the error messages?

Comment: I want the repository/client to say to the caller, "Hey, your object isn't saving and here's why:...".

Comment: Sure. But what do you expect the caller to _do_ with the error messages? Write them to the batch log? If that's the case, then all you need is a single, formatted error message. A long one, possibly, but all you need is a text string.

Comment: It'll be logged and saved with the batch. The way our system works needs each message to be an individual string. I could make it delimited and split it into a list at the caller but that seems inelegant.

Comment: Then simply return a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Typically in this situation I will try to fit the exceptions that can arise into the framework exceptions first, where that makes sense, and/or then I'll make custom exceptions for any others. You can provide your own custom messages.

Comment: I'm on the client side consuming the web service.

Comment: Right, but what if you have a list of, say, 10 error messages the web service sent back that you want to provide with the exception?

Comment: How about maintaining a log at the repository and simply send the caller back a reference to the logfile or uri.